# How to push a project from local to another existing remote repository branch?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a project from a repository. Then changed the project. Now I want to push this project to a existing branch. Suppose I cloned from A. Now I want to push it on my B1 branch of B. which already a remote repo.

Comment: Are A and B two different remotes?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to realize here that *branches* don't really matter.  What really matter are *commits*.

A Git repository is, primarily, a collection of commits.  When you clone a repository, you copy all of its commits.<sup>1</sup>  So you duplicate this big database, of all commit objects and other supporting objects.

In order to *find* the commits *in* a repository, Git needs names: branch names, tag names, and other kinds of names.  When you clone a repository, you may—at your discretion—copy all their *tag* names, but you don't copy their *branch* names.  Instead, your Git takes their *branch* names and turns those into your *remote-tracking* names.  So you don't duplicate this smaller names database.  Instead, your Git software, working on your Git repository (which all together, I call "your Git") creates a separate names database just for your Git repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>In some cases, you *can* copy fewer than *all* commits, but this is generally the way to think about it.

---

With this in mind:

> I have cloned a project from a repository.

Git doesn't define the term *project*.  You cloned a repository.  This made a new repository, into which your Git copied all the commits and other internal objects supplied by their Git.  Your Git took their branch names, and made them into remote-tracking names (`origin/main` and the like) and put those in your clone.

> Then changed the project.

It's not at all clear what this means.  Given a repository, what you generally do with it is *add new commits*.  Let's assume you added some new commits, for now.

> Now I want to push this project to a existing branch.

That doesn't really make any sense.  A repository contains *commits*.  The commits are linked to each other: each commit has a number—some big ugly hash ID, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), that looks random but is actually a cryptographic checksum of the commit's content including its metadata—and each commit remembers the raw hash ID of some earlier commit.

To find the commits in your repository here, your Git will use your repository's branch names, and your repository's tag names if any, and your repository's remote-tracking names, and so on.  Each name will locate exactly *one* commit, but that one commit will usually have the hash ID of one *earlier* commit in it.  These commits form a backwards-looking chain:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

where the name `main` finds the hash ID of the *latest* commit `H` (`H` just stands in for some actual hash ID, which *looks* random, even though it isn't random at all).  Commit `H` in turn stores the hash ID of earlier commit `G`, which stores the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.  This repeats down the line to the very first commit, which we can call `A`.

Since this particular repository is a clone of some other repository, this repository has in it, every commit that *they* had, plus the ones you added.  Your branch name, whatever it is, points to the last commit you added.  That commit points backwards to earlier commit(s); this eventually leads into the commits they supplied to your Git; those eventually lead back to the very first commit `A`.

This is the *history* in a repository: we start at each "last commit" (as found by one or more branch names), and then have Git work backwards.  When we have two or more branches, there may—or may not!—be more than one "last commit":

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

Here, there are three "last commits": the last commit on `main` is `H`; the last commit on `feature1` is `J`; and the last commit on `feature2` is `L`.  Note that commits up through and including `H` are on *all three branches*, despite `H` being the *last* commit on `main`.

When we clone a repository that has several branches, our own Git will create *one* branch in the new clone, but we'll have remote-tracking names for each of their *branch* names:

```
          I--J   <-- origin/feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/feature2
```

We can also have situations where more than one branch name all point to one specific commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), develop, feature
```

which is what we'd get if we made a repository with one branch named `main`, and then—after making some commits—created two new branches from `main` but did not make any new commits after that point yet.

This is what commits and branches mean, in a Git repository.  Each commit stores a full snapshot of every file, plus some metadata: the metadata tells who made the commit, when, and why (their log message), and has other useful stuff, including the raw hash ID of some earlier commit(s), which allows Git to work backwards.  The history in the repository is the commits in the repository: that is all there is, and that is all we need.  The branch and other names find the commits from which Git can work backwards.

> Now I want to push it on my B1 branch of B ...

You'll need to define what you mean by *it*.

If you want *all the history* from your clone to appear in your repository B, you will have to add *all the commits* from your clone to repository B.  This is not particularly difficult, but there are two catches:

- However many "last commits" you have and care about, you need one branch name for each such commit.  If you only care about the commits from the last one on (say) `main` backwards, you only need one branch name.
- When you push some commit, you automatically push *all earlier commits*, so that you end up with the *same chain* appearing in the destination repository.  That is, by pushing commit `H`, you'll automatically push commits `G`, `F`, and so on, all the way back to `A`—but `A` will be the *first* commit.

If the target repository already has one "first commit", you end up with a repository with two separate first commits.  **This is allowed!**  We might draw such a repository like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- one

D--E--F--G   <-- two (HEAD)
```

Here, commit `C` is the last commit on the three-commit chain that ends at `C` and works backwards to `A` and then stops.  Separately, `G` is the last commit on the five-commit chain that ends there and works backwards to `D` and then stops.

These two histories are *unrelated*.  There's no commonality between them: no shared starting point.  So they cannot be merged, at least not sensibly.

This also means that you need a minimum of two branch names: one to find `C`, which is the last commit (of one chain), and one to find `G`, which is also the last commit (of a different, independent chain).

**If this is what you want** the whole thing is trivial:

```
git push <name-or-url> main:B
```

will create a *new* branch name `B` in the target URL.  New branch name `B` will identify the same commit that the name `main` identifies in the Git repository you're in when you run `git push`.

The *`name-or-url`* part here can be a *remote name*, or a raw URL, or even a path to another repository.  All you are doing is having your Git—your various commands working on your repository—call up some other Git, perhaps on another machine, and sending to it all the commits that you have, that they don't, that end at the commit found by your `main` here.  Then you have your Git ask their Git to set *their* name `B` to identify that last commit.

This *cannot add commits on* to any existing branch in their repository because we've assumed independent / unrelated histories.  So branch name `B` must not exist in their repository.

#### Key points

`git push` is about sending *commits*, not files.

Git itself is about *commits*, not files.  Commits store files, but you either have the whole commit, or none of it.  You extract one commit—which gets you all the files from that commit—and then do some work and then, usually, make a *new commit*.  The new commit's history is that it connects back to the commit you checked out.  The files *in* the new commit are those from the old commit, with whatever changes you made to your working tree and ran `git add` on to put back into Git.

To transfer history, you will transfer whole commits.  To get some set of files into some other Git repository, without dealing with the whole *history*, you're better off just going to the other repository and copying the files into your working tree there and running `git add`.

If you want or need different commits than the commits you have right now, you are going to have to build the new commits.

Comment: I accepted this answer because now the concept is very clear to me( though my problem was different). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### There are two possible cases.

#### 1. A is a fork of B

In this case, the commit history will match at some point. So if you are using Github, then you can directly create a pull request of merging commits of A into `B1` branch of B.

Alternatively, if you have `push privileges` for B , then you can just add another remote in your local git repository(**Conventionally**, this remote is named `upstream`)

```
git remote add upstream <git://github.com/../..git>
```

(Replace `<...>` with URL of B)

After that, you can normally push into B by

```
git push upstream <branchname>
```

#### 2. A and B are totally different repositories

In this case, you cannot do anything since they donot have the same commit history at any point. However in this case, you can add a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) of A in B.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned from A and B with a different location. Modify A as per I need, then copy all files without the .git file(found it by enabling hidden file). Then paste it to B and push it to the B1 branch. This may be weird but that's how I solved it finally.